# SVN Configuration

Tags: svn

I have installed SVN on a local machine and created a repository there. Now I am trying to access that repository from other machine in same network. I tried every type of URL to checkout but everything failed. Machine having repository is a linux machine and other one is windows. Is there any link where I can diagnose it step by step.???

Comment: Which errors you're getting? Is it a network problem, or an error on application layer?

Comment: When I enter a path, it asks for password and again and again it keeps asking same. and then throw an error unable to find out repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't start *any Subversion server* on host with repo, you can only use file:/// protocol and have repository on shared SMB-drive.

If repo-drive is shared and you can see repository-folder in Explorer from other side, usename-password will not be asked (file:/// is anonymous access)

If you get auth-requests, you must configure users and access rights before accessing repository, on the side of server

**Note:** If you'll show **real commands and outputs** it will be easier to debug - we can't read mind